# Adding line numbers to stacktrace with build.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build.xml

I'm working on a java project in eclipse, and recently I found the need to recreate my build.xml as I accidentally wipe s the contents of the old one (woops). Now, when I went to debug my work, the stracktrace says unknown source where it should show my line numbers and the file it belongs to. I utilize this so I know exactly where in my code to look for the issues. Without this it's kind of hard to search through my code looking for the error.

Below is my build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="FoolishPlugin">
   <description>Creates the plugin of the fools...</description>
   <path id="Foolish Plugin.classpath">
    <!-- Spare you the details -->
   </path>
   <path id="Maven Dependencies.libraryclasspath">
      <!-- Spare you this long list of stuff -->
   </path>
   <!-- set global properties for this build -->
   <property name="src" location="src" />
   <property name="build" location="build" />
   <property name="dist" location="dist" />
   <property name="version" value="1.0" />
   <!-- init -->
   <target name="init">
      <!-- Create the time stamp -->
      <tstamp />
      <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
      <mkdir dir="${build}" />
   </target>
   <!-- compile -->
   <target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source">
      <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
      <javac debug="true" debuglevel="lines" srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" includeantruntime="false">
         <classpath refid="Foolish Plugin.classpath" />
      </javac>
   </target>
   <target name="create-funky-jar" depends="compile" description="Creates the jar ya filthy animal">
      <buildnumber />
      <!-- Create the distribution direct ory -->
      <mkdir dir="${dist}/lib" />
      <copy todir="${build}">
         <fileset dir="resources/" />
      </copy>
      <!-- Put everything in ${build} into the MyApplication-${version}.${build.number}.jar -->
      <jar destfile="${dist}/lib/Fools-${version}.${build.number}.jar" basedir="${build}" />
   </target>
</project>
```

I tried researching what to do to bring back the line numbers specifically, and the suggestions I found were to set the debug tag to true and the debuglevel to lines, which both I added, (as can be seen in the paste). However, neither has made a difference as I'm still getting the unknown source message on my stack trace.

Any ideas?

Comment: If I remember correctly javac skips the compile if the .class already exists and is newer than the source .java - so you need to erase the .class files to make sure they are recompiled with those options.